# Extract Names of Images Pasted into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a listing of books in an Excel file into existing Access catalogue database and my research has come up empty. The file has over 4700 rows with one entry per book per row. About 850 rows also have an image of the book’s cover in column A. My problem is that the row text imports successfully into the Access database unfortunately the images do not.

What I would like to do is extract the Excel image number from a picture and write that to a cell on the same row eg picture is in A3 and the image number would be written to cell B3. I can then import the image name number into Access. This database has provision for linking to external images and I would just have to copy the Excel images to a common location.

I have been able to locate the images in Excel and export them into a separate folder. They were called image1.jpeg to imagexxx.jpeg in Excel and I have kept these names.

I have attempted to extract the image name from the worksheet using:
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 213")).Select
However, there seems to be no relationship between this name and the images  I have. Image213 is not the same as the one I tested against.

I’m looking for a way to associate the images I have extracted from Excel with their respective rows.

Excel and Access versions are 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getImageInfo()

    Dim img As Shape

    For Each img In ActiveSheet.Shapes

        MsgBox "Image Name: " & img.Name & ", Image top row: " & img.TopLeftCell.Row

    Next

End Sub
```